# Continuity of local spectral radius

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-radius

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space and let $T \in \mathcal{B}(H)$ be a linear, bounded operator. Given $x \in H$ we define its local spectral radius as $$r_T(x) = \limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \|T^nx\|^{1/n}.$$
Now, let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence converging to $x$. I've been looking for any results to assure the convergence of the local spectral radius, id est, $r_T(x_n) \rightarrow r_T(x)$. Obviously this convergence cannot happen for every operator and for every vector, but I would like to know if anyone knows any condition to assure this convergence.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know if the terminology is standard but if not, I'd rather call it "pointwise spectral radius".

Comment: @YCor: Actually, the terminology is standard. There's an entire field called "local spectral theory" that deals with local - in the sense of "pointwise" - spectral properties.